# Async function undefined despite binding

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm struggling to figure out why the function storeEmailVerified() in my React Native code below returns undefined. Here is the error message:

> that.storeEmailVerified is not a function. (In
>   'that.storeEmailVerified("true")', 'that.storeEmailVerified' is
>   undefined)

I have bound both of the following functions to 'this' in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.storeEmailVerified = this.storeEmailVerified.bind(this);
  this.checkEmailVerified = this.checkEmailVerified.bind(this);
}

checkEmailVerified = async () => {
   let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref().child("/users").child(currentUser).on("value", function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const emailVerified = snapshot.child("emailVerified").val();
        if (emailVerified == true) {
          this.setState({
            emailVerified: true
          })
          this.storeEmailVerified("true");
          // AsyncStorage.setItem("emailVerified", true)
        }
        else {
          this.setState({
            emailVerified: false
          })
          this.storeEmailVerified("false");
          // AsyncStorage.setItem("emailVerified", false)
        }
      }
    });
  };

  storeEmailVerified = async status => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("emailVerified", status)
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
      return 'error'
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's because use aren't `return`ing anything from it

Comment: @DominikMatis Thanks for your response. I updated the code and added a return, but the error message is the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: yeah, it's because of `that` in `checkEmailVerified`....`this` is a pointer to that function, not a class in this case

Comment: The `that = this` bit is a hack and in this case doesn't work because by the time you call it `this` is already pointing at the wrong thing. You should use an arrow function or explicitly `bind()` the function if you want to preserve the lexical `this`.

Comment: Maybe try to change those functions into arrow functions, so it does not propagate `this`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I had previously tried replacing 'that' with 'this', and just tried it again, but am still ending up with undefined functions despite the binding in the constructor. Now it is this.setState that is undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have also updated the functions to arrow functions as you can see in the code above. this.setState is undefined

Comment: @DominikMatis Thanks. I have changed the functions to arrow functions as you suggested. You can see my changes in the code above. However, I get "this.setState is not a function". Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks fo your suggestions. I tried changing the functions to arrow functions (see my updated code above), but this still refers to the wrong context. I now get "this.setState is not a functions". Any suggestions what might still be wrong about the way I'm using "this"?

Comment: @luciusdegeer you need the arrow function where you pass the function as an event handler in `.on("value",...` not `checkEmailVerified = async () => {`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Like this? .on("value", () => (snapshot) {

Comment: @luciusdegeer close, more like `.on("value",  (snapshot) =>  {`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you SO much. That had been bogging me down for way too long. I didn't realize firebase would break the context. Thank you!